# What tool breaks up raster cells into individual values based upon contiguity?

Tags: raster, arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, land-cover

[image: The green values have a COUNT attribute of 13418]

The green values have a COUNT attribute of 13418.
I will want to use a tool that lumps the COUNT attribute and reclassifies based on values. But first it appears I will need to break up the raster cells into individual values using a tool? I am learning raster, in the past I only used vector.

Comment: Your question has many different possible interpretations. Could you please tell us (a) whether you are making a distinction between the `Count` attribute and a "value" and (b) what it means to "break up" raster cells?

Comment: I need a tool that breaks up the Forestland into individual values based upon contiguity.
Then use a tool that looks at the “COUNT” attribute (total cells) and reclassifies based on this value. Eventually I  want to be in a Contiguous Forest Block (the green cells) that is comprised of at least 1000 Unbroken Cells.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean by "break up" the forestland.  Are you perhaps describing a [RegionGroup](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Region_Group/009z00000039000000/) operation?  BTW, please make explicit the software you would like to use (from the screen shot I would guess it is Spatial Analyst).

Comment: The counts of the raster data are concentrated as one value (the green box with a one). I need the values dispersed and individualized based on contiguity (where they touch another).

Comment: Sorry for any unclearness, and yes only spatial analyst tools

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the [Region Group tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000039000000.htm) in the spatial analyst toolset.  It allows you to "regroup" your clusters of like values, while allowing you to ignore NoData cells.  You can also specify the type of neighborhood.  The raster attribute table will then contain a count of cells in each group.  I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! You all were correct in suggesting the RegionGroup operation, it broke up my resulting grid into individual values; that I later reclassified and factored out cells with  less than a '1000' cell count.